# How to DRY out my Django Views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

As my Django skill level increases, I am beginning to see my code differently and am desperate to find a way to not repeat myself in my views - as seen below.  An example of how my views should be setup would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from listings.models import Listing
from posts.models import Reveal


def home(request):
    return render(request, "pages/home.html", {})


def about(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, 'pages/about.html', {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def team(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/theteam.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def why(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/why.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def services(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/services.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def selling_facts(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/selling_facts.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def buying_facts(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/buying_facts.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def liquor_licenses(request):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    return render(request, "pages/liquor_licenses.html", {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})


def contact(request):
    return render(request, "pages/contact.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your url to reflect what purpose does it serve by defining a url named parameter. You capture that in a single view and render different pages depend on that parameter:

```
# url definition
url(r'^pages/(?P<page>\w+)/$', views.render_pages, name='render-pages')

# your views
from django.http import Http404

def _get_template_by_parameter(page):
    if page == 'about':
        return 'pages/about.html'
    elif page == 'team':
        return 'pages/theteam.html'
    # some more branches here
    return None

def render_pages(request, page):
    reveals = Reveal.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1:1]
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(featured_choices="YES").order_by('?')[:1:1]
    template = _get_template_by_parameter(page)
    if template:
        return render(request, template, {'listings': listings, 'reveals': reveals})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

You could visit your url like: http://test.com/pages/about or http://test.com/pages/team. Apparently you need better wording because I'm just coding it up quickly.

Comment: Thank you Shang; this looks way cleaner! I will give it a go this evening when I sit back down to work.